# ImageView OnClickListener() not getting called in Activity

Tags: android, imageview, onclicklistener

I have the following ImageViews defined in a RelativeLayout:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/forward"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/chevron_left_disabled" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/back"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/chevron_right_disabled" />
```

In my Activity, they are referenced as follows:

```
mFwdButton = findViewById(R.id.forward);
    mFwdButton.setEnabled(false);
    mFwdButton.setClickable(true);
    mFwdButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (browser_page.canGoForward()) {
                browser_page.goForward();
            } else {
                mFwdButton.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(R.drawable.chevron_right_disabled));
            }
        }
    });

    mBackButton = findViewById(R.id.back);
    mBackButton.setEnabled(false);
    mBackButton.setClickable(true);
    mBackButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (browser_page.canGoBack()) {
                browser_page.goBack();
            } else {
                mBackButton.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(R.drawable.chevron_left_disabled));
            }
        }
    });
```

I set a breakpoint after onClick() in each ImageView element, but it's never hit. Any ideas? I already tried out what was suggested in SO, but nothing resolved the problem.

Comment: You've used `mBackButton.setEnabled(false);` which *could* be the problem.

Comment: @Darshan Damn! That's what I get for blindly copying code from another project. Right after I posted my question, I noticed that. Thanks! Please post as the answer and I'll give you the credit, Darshan.